# JQuery Javascript Populate Data Class

Tags: javascript, jquery, soap

I need some assistance. I am at a very basic level of programming and not all that familiar with JQuery, so I am sure this may seem like a very basic question. Please stick with me. I have searched and searched and have not found an answer I can seem to apply to my project. Very sorry if this is a duplicate question.

//-----------------------Web Service Function - GetData()

```
<GetDataResult>
<exm>string</exm>   //Success or Failure message
<nrs>int</nrs>      //Number of Users
<data>
    <datainfo>
        <tid>string</tid>
        <dat>string</dat>
        <sig>string</sig>
        <rac>string</rac>
         <moreinfo>
            <pst>string</pst>
            <stl>string</stl>
            <nam>string</nam>   
        </moreinfo>
        <moreinfo>
            <pst>string</pst>
            <stl>string</stl>
            <nam>string</nam>   
        </moreinfo>
    <datainfo>
        <tid>string</tid>
        <dat>string</dat>
        <sig>string</sig>
        <rac>string</rac>
        <moreinfo>
            <pst>string</pst>
            <stl>string</stl>
            <nam>string</nam>   
        </moreinfo>
        <moreinfo>
            <pst>string</pst>
            <stl>string</stl>
            <nam>string</nam>   
        </moreinfo>       
    </datainfo>
</data>
</GetDataResult>
```

I have no clue how to handle the returned data from this web service. Assuming I use `myObj` for the object name... and `di` for "data info"... and `mi` for "more info". What I want to be able to do is take this data, populate an object, and be able to refer to the different values in this manner...

```
var exm = myObj.exm
var nrs = myObj.nrs   

for( i = 0; i <= nrs; i++ ){
    tids[i] = myObj.di[i].tid;
    dats[i] = myObj.di[i].dat;
    sigs[i] = myObj.di[i].sig;
    racs[i] = myObj.di[i].rac;

    for( j = 0; j <= idx; j++ ){
        psts[j] = myObj.di[i].mi[j].pst;
        stls[j] = myObj.di[i].mi[j].stl;
        nams[j] = myObj.di[i].mi[j].nam;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: So, you're trying to get and parse an xml request from a server? If so, look at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ . A jquery Ajax request should let you do both of those things in one step.

Comment: And if you already have the xml data, you can use http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/ to parse it.

Comment: @VictorioBerra  jQuery can be used for xml also. Sure JSON is easier to work with but your statement is inaccurate

Comment: Exactly @slicedtoad. I will have a look right now.

Comment: @SeanBarber It might be a bit of a struggle but by looking at the docs and some examples you should be able at least get something close to what you want. Once you do, post what you have and someone can tell you what's wrong.

Comment: I am connecting successfully, I am getting the data correctly. The code I am working with does in fact return all the values. My issue is much less complicated. Where I need help is... after getting the data back from the web service, I create arrays containing the values... but how do I take the arrays I created, and create object containing said arrays? The amount will be dynamic. Once I do that I am able to refer to the object and retrieve values using dot notation right?

Comment: @slicedtoad Have a look at the XML I had in my fist post... I do an each loop for the values in 'datainfo' (based on the number returned from 'nrs')... I then have (4) arrays containing 'tid' 'dat' 'sig' and 'rac' values... then within that same 'datainfo' loop I do another each loop for 'moreinfo' and retrieve 'pst' 'stl' 'nam' values and create (3) more arrays... how do I take these values, and the follow the same structure so that I can refer to the object in a loop in this manner... for(i=0;i<=nrs;i++) { for(j=0;j<=2;j++) { alert(myObj.datainfo[i].moreinfo[j].nam);} ?

Comment: object creation in JS is really easy. `var myobj = {propname:propValue, anotherPropName:anotherPropValue,...}` where propname is what you will be using to identify it with dot notation and propvalue can be anything including arrays `propname:[1,2,3]` or other objects `propname:{aObj,bObj,cObj}`.

Comment: if you hardcode some arrays into a fiddle, I can show you how to transform them but it's too hard to figure out exactly what you need just from descriptions. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: for each 'datainfo'
  tids = [a,b,c,d]
  dats = [2001,2002,2003,2004]
  sigs = [a,a,e,e]
  racs = [1,2,3,4]

for each 'moreinfo' within each 'datainfo'
  psts = [1,2,3,4]
  stls = [5,6,7,8]
  nams = [Bob,Sam,Pat,Joe]

Comment: this will do it pretty well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach